# R plotting margins & dotted y-axis

Tags: r

Is there anyway to replace your y-axis with instead a dotted line for the plot function?

Also, how do you increase the margins around your entire plot area? Can this be specified in layout?

If you look below the edge of my window is next to average temperature.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question , you can use `axis` , for example:

```
> plot(1:10,  axes=FALSE)      ### to not plot the default ones
> axis(1,lty='dashed',lwd=3)
> axis(2,lty=3,lwd=2)
```

The second part is not clear. You can't specify margin inside layout command.

[image]

**EDIT** set outer margins of the plot.

By default, there are no outer margins on a page. Outer margins can be
    specified using the **oma** graphics state setting. This consists of four values for
    the four margins in the order (bottom, left, top, right) and values are with unit lines.

for example:

```
     old.oma <- par(oma=c(5,5,0,1))  #bottom 5 lines,left 5lines,right 1line
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your clear response. My guess was that the overall graph margins could be specified in layout. If not, could you direct me to where I might be able to find them?

Comment: @Django it is not clear but I guess you want to modifify the boundaries around your plot. You cas see `par('oma'), par('omd')`..